# How to start a java-web-start application and wait until it exits?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I just found out that `javaws -wait` doesn't do what is supposed to do on Windows. It will return before the aplication finishes.

This bug is more than 5 years old and closed as won't fix
[6281477](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6281477), so we need a workaround.

I looking for a clean solution that will:

- run unattended (no user intervention):

  - currently if JNLP file is not accessible, Java will display an error window.
- if application fails for any reason we need a return code different from 0

It would be preferable to have a cross platform solution for this Java or Python but it would be acceptable even a Windows batch solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your bullet points - these are not even proper sentences. Could you correct that? It's easier to get answers if people understand your question :-).

Comment: Sorry, I hope that now is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your application to be booted from the web (which, from your question, I assume is the case), use javaw instead.

I believe it will give what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, but here is an alternative to `javaws -wait`: `javaws` will start a `javaw` process with `com.sun.javaws.Main` as main class.

The `jcmd` can come to the rescue:

```
while jcmd com.sun.javaws.Main PerfCounter.print > /dev/null 2> /dev/null  ; do
  echo "still running !"
  sleep 2
done
```

One down side of this is to determine the actual java cmd: if multiple webstart application are ran, then the command will exit only if all application are down.